# use int array in string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a int array with for example {1,2,3,4} value.

I want to put this numbers into, for example, my list box like this :

```
listBox2.Items.Add("After Inserting (" + page[i].ToString() + ')' + <use all my numbers like this : 1234 here>+"Page Fault = " + pf.ToString());
```

Output :

```
After Inserting (3) 1234 page fault = 5
```

1234 is just an example. My array is much bigger.

How can I do that in c#?

Comment: Try to be expressive in plain english first then coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) (actually the `IEnumerable<T>` overload is taken):

```
String joined = String.Join("", yourArray);
```

> i'm new in c# how i dont know how place the string among the text

You can use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) to build the text and to increase readability:

```
var inserted = page[i].ToString();
var allInserted = String.Join("", yourArray);
var pageFault = pf.ToString();
var itemText = String.Format("After Inserting ({0}) {1} page fault = {2}"
                             ,inserted, allInserted, pageFault);
listBox2.Items.Add(itemText);
```

**Edit 2**:

> can i replace some Character instead one number in array? my array :
>   {1,2,3,4,-1"} output : 1,2,3,4,empty

Yes, you can replace the output:

```
String.Join("", yourArray.Where(i => i != -1));
```

**Edit 3**:

> i understand how i can exclude -1 but i didn't understand how i can
>   replace something with that...like "empty" instead -1

Here we go ...

```
String.Join(", ", intArray.Select(i => i == -1 ? "empty" : i.ToString()));
```

Comment: i'm new in c#, i dont know how place it among the string, can u edit my code in the first post and show me how?
just like output of first post...thanks

Comment: Just FYI, you can use the `String.Join` overload that takes an `object[]` - saves one explicit step, same .NET version requirement

Comment: @skarmats: Thanks for the reminder. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: tbh, I don't know which overload is used. Could be the one that takes `IEnumerable<T>` ;) The general point remains. Maybe someone can enlighten me about the resolution chain

Comment: @skarmats: Good question, actually it's [this third overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx)  which takes `IEnumerable<T>`(my first approach took [`IEnumerable<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)).

Comment: can i replace some Character instead one number in array?
my array : {1,2,3,4,-1"}
output : 1,2,3,4,empty

Comment: @Nima: Edited my answer. Is it correct that you want to exclude `-1` from output or do you want to show it as _"empty"_ (note: not white-space)?

Comment: @Nima: I see, that differs from your original requirement to get `1234` as result since `string.Join(", "...` will separate them with commas. Aside from the fact that this is another question, i'll edit my answer again.

Comment: @Tim : i understand how i can exclude -1 but i didn't understand how i can replace something with that...like "empty" instead -1

Comment: i can't, my reputation is 1 :D

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Join(", ", intArray.Select(i => i.ToString()))
```

Comment: i'm new in c#, i dont know how place it among the string, can u edit my code in the first post and show me how?
just like output of first post...thanks

Comment: Like this: 
`listBox2.Items.Add("After Inserting (" + page[i].ToString() + ') ' + string.Join(", ", intArray.Select(i => i.ToString())) + " Page Fault = " + pf.ToString());`

Comment: can i replace some Character instead one number in array? my array : {1,2,3,4,-1"} output : 1,2,3,4,empty

Answer (score 2):

string.Join works also with ToList()

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
string s = string.Join("", numbers.ToList());
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

output is = "12345"

EDIT: I don't know the name of your array, so I still use the above numbers example

```
listBox2.Items.Add("After Inserting (" + page[i].ToString() + ") " + 
                    string.Join("", numbers.ToList()) + 
                    " Page Fault = " + pf.ToString());
```

EDIT:

To exclude numbers like -1 then

```
int[] numeri = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,-1};
string s = string.Join(",", numeri.Where(i => i != -1).ToList());
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Note, added a comma to separate the numbers

Comment: i'm new in c#, i dont know how place it among the string, can u edit my code in the first post and show me how?
just like output of first post...thanks

Comment: can i replace some Character instead one number in array? my array : {1,2,3,4,-1"} output : 1,2,3,4,empty